# Conditional sorting / reordering of column values in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data set similar to the following with 1 column and 60 rows:

```
    value 
 1 0.0423 
 2 0.0388 
 3 0.0386 
 4 0.0342 
 5 0.0296 
 6 0.0276 
 7 0.0246 
 8 0.0239 
 9 0.0234 
10 0.0214 
 .
40 0.1424
 .
60 -0.0312
```

I want to reorder the rows so that certain conditions are met. For example one condition could be: `sum(df$value[4:7]) > 0.1000` &  `sum(df$value[4:7]) <0.1100`

With the data set looking like this for example.

```
    value 
 1 0.0423 
 2 0.0388 
 3 0.0386 
 4 0.1312
 5 -0.0312
 6 0.0276 
 7 0.0246 
 8 0.0239 
 9 0.0234 
10 0.0214 
 .
 .
 .
60 0.0342
```

What I tried was using `repeat` and `sample` as in the following:

```
repeat{ 
       df1 <- as_tibble(sample(sdf$value, replace = TRUE))
    if (sum(df$value[4:7]) > 0.1000 &  sum(df$value[4:7]) <0.1100) break
    }
```

Unfortunately, this method takes quite some time and I was wondering if there is a faster way to reorder rows based on mathematical conditions such as `sum` or `prod`

Comment: Based on your last question, I think it's important to ask if you have multiple conditions you need to apply simultaneously? That might change the approach significantly.

Comment: Reshuffling and waiting until you get lucky isn't a great strategy. Perhaps just sort the data in order, then calculate a rolling sum of each 4 rows. Find 4 rows that meet your criteria, and put them wherever you want.

Comment: If you can come up with a continuous measure of distance from your desired state, you can sometimes use a hill-climbing type method where you randomly select a pair of rows, swap them, and see if you've gotten closer to the goal. More efficient than resampling the whole dataset at once and starting from scratch, although it's not necessarily guaranteed to get to an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation of the hill-climbing method I outlined in my comment. I've had to slightly reframe the desired condition as "distance of `sum(x[4:7])` from 0.105" to make it continuous, although you can still use the exact condition when doing the check that all requirements are satisfied. The benefit is that you can add extra conditions to the distance function easily.

```
# Using same example data as Jon Spring
set.seed(42)
vs = rnorm(60, 0.05, 0.08)

get_distance = function(x) {
    distance = abs(sum(x[4:7]) - 0.105)
    # Add to the distance with further conditions if needed
    distance
}

max_attempts = 10000
best_distance = Inf

swaps_made = 0
for (step in 1:max_attempts) {
    # Copy the vector and swap two random values
    new_vs = vs
    swap_inds = sample.int(length(vs), 2, replace = FALSE)
    new_vs[swap_inds] = rev(new_vs[swap_inds])

    # Keep the new vector if the distance has improved
    new_distance = get_distance(new_vs)
    if (new_distance < best_distance) {
        vs = new_vs
        best_distance = new_distance
        swaps_made = swaps_made + 1
    }

    complete = (sum(vs[4:7]) < 0.11) & (sum(vs[4:7]) > 0.1)
    if (complete) {
        print(paste0("Solution found in ", step, " steps"))
        break
    }
}

sum(vs[4:7])
```

There's no real guarantee that this method will reach a solution, but I often try this kind of basic hill-climbing when I'm not sure if there's a "smart" way to approach a problem.

Comment: Nice approach. In order to avoid getting stuck into local minima, you may try Simulated Annealing, which allows to make some downhill moves with a small proba (function of the "temperature"). This proba decreases at each search iteration. Implemented in package GenSA, but I haven't checked it

Comment: Thank you very much! I think with 60 rows its might be better to move the rows by hand though in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `combn` from base R, and then filtering using `dplyr`. (I'm sure there's a way w/o it but my base-fu isn't there yet.)

With only 4 numbers from a pool of 60, there are "only" 488k different combinations (ignoring order; =60*59*58*57/4/3/2), so it's quick to brute force in about a second.

```
# Make a vector of 60 numbers like your example
set.seed(42)
my_nums <- rnorm(60, 0.05, 0.08); 

all_combos <- combn(my_nums, 4)  # Get all unique combos of 4 numbers

library(tidyverse)
combos_table <- all_combos %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(sum = V1 + V2 + V3 + V4) %>%
  filter(sum > 0.1, sum < 0.11)


> combos_table
# A tibble: 8,989 x 5
      V1      V2      V3       V4   sum
   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.160 0.00482  0.0791 -0.143   0.100
 2 0.160 0.00482  0.101  -0.163   0.103
 3 0.160 0.00482  0.0823 -0.145   0.102
 4 0.160 0.00482  0.0823 -0.143   0.104
 5 0.160 0.00482 -0.0611 -0.00120 0.102
 6 0.160 0.00482 -0.0611  0.00129 0.105
 7 0.160 0.00482  0.0277 -0.0911  0.101
 8 0.160 0.00482  0.0277 -0.0874  0.105
 9 0.160 0.00482  0.101  -0.163   0.103
10 0.160 0.00482  0.0273 -0.0911  0.101
# … with 8,979 more rows
```

This says that in this example, there are about 9000 different sets of 4 numbers from my sequence which meet the criteria. We could pick any of these and put them in positions 4-7 to meet your requirement.